# Vue show next amount of items of array

Tags: arrays, methods, vuejs2, computed-properties

I want to make a button which shows the next 2 items in my array.

The *initial* amount of the array should be 2 and then when pressing the button it should extend the array with 2 items and so on. When there is only 1 item the button should not be visible.

How can I achieve this? Can I use the `slice()` method for this?

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-hoover-3jibg) is what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slice instead on your computed filteredData with second argument of the slice to be a key that you can modify to tell how many you want the page to show. I will call this `productsToShow`.

```
data: () => ({
    productsToShow: 2,
    products: [...]
}),
computed: {
    filteredData() {
      const LowerCaseSearch = this.search.toLowerCase();
      const filteredProducts = this.products.filter(
        product =>
          product.name.toLowerCase().includes(LowerCaseSearch) ||
          product.category.toLowerCase().includes(LowerCaseSearch)
      );
      
      return filteredProducts.slice(0, this.productsToShow);
    }
}
```

Then you can modify your `ShowNext` component-button to emit an event that the parent (`List.vue`) can listen on to then change the key: `productsToShow`

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-perlman-uhd11

Comment: do you have maybe an idea on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62612991/use-methods-and-computed-properties-in-child-component)?