# Use methods and computed properties in child component

Tags: methods, vuejs2, vue-component

In my `List` component I have a method which count the length of the array within certain categories.

```
methods: {
    getLengthofaCategory(cat) {
      const LowerCaseSearch = this.search.toLowerCase();
      let categoryCount = this.products.filter(
        product =>
          (product.name.toLowerCase().includes(LowerCaseSearch) ||
            product.category.toLowerCase().includes(LowerCaseSearch)) &&
          (!this.checked.length || this.checked.includes(product.category)) &&
          product.category === cat
      );

      return categoryCount.length;
    }
  }
```

See here my setup in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-stonebraker-vx0y5?file=/src/components/List.vue).

But I want the values next to the checkboxes (which are coming from my `CheckBox` component).

How do I get the logic from the method `getLengthofaCategory` into my `CheckBox` component?

So I am able to use {{ getLengthofaCategory('tennis') }} in the v-for loop, inside the `CheckBox` component. And then maybe I can also use `category.value` instead of hardcoding e.g 'tennis' as the paramater?

Answer (score 0):

In your list.vue, you can use the already created computed function `filteredData` instead of doing the filter again. This saves some performance because in Vue, computed properties are "cached" once run.

So you can create a new computed function that creates an object with keys per category and value can either be just the amount or an array of products in this category.

I would then pass this computed value to the `CheckBox` component via a prop, then inside the `CheckBox` component, you can display the .length or value regarding how many items each category has:

List.vue:

```
    computed: {
    //...
      amountPerCategory() {
        return this.filteredData.reduce((categories, product) => {
          if (!(product.category in categories)) {
            categories[product.category] = [];
          }

          categories[product.category].push(product);

          return categories;
        }, {});
      }
    }
```

CheckBox.vue:

```
        <span class="ml-2 text-gray-700 capitalize">{{ category.value }}</span> -
        <span
          v-if="count[category.value]"
          class="ml-2 text-gray-700 capitalize"
        >{{ count[category.value].length }}</span>
```

```
 count: {
   type: Object,
   default: () => ({})
 }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-ellis-4hojl?file=/src/components/CheckBox.vue